# reset bios on a acer 5050

Tags: passwords, bios

Besides tacking off the cmos battery, what else can I do In order to reset my BIOS to default? ATM bios access is password protected and I don't know the password anymore.

On regular PC stations, there was a jumper, but where is that on a laptop mobo?

Do you know any other way of resetting the bios on a laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a windows download you can try or linux source code. The site also includes other techniques. Check it out.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/CmosPwd

Answer (score 1):

Get your Fujitsu-Siemens and Acer bios master password here. They also do this for Dell, HP/Compaq, Samsung and Sony 
Just go to http://www.mastermindit.biz/fujitsusiemensbios.html
The Master Password will delete all Bios passwords giving you access to your locked computer again

Answer (score 1):

I literally just had the same issue, here is what I did:

GOT IT !!

Turns out there is a page which has the generic BIOS unlock codes.

1. Enter BIOS and put any password 3 times, BIOS will lock
2. Select option to put password and below you will find a number
3. Enter the number in this website https://bios-pw.org/
4. You will be prompted the number for your device, enter into the BIOS
5. Congratulations !! You may now move the settings in the BIOS.